# How to fill data of PostgreSQL into combobox using jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql

I want to fetch data from PostgreSQL into my Combobox using query Ajax in html page.

Here is the code of popup box where I want to fetch the data:

```
<html>
<body>
        <script src="../webmap/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function dropdown(){
        $('#a1_title').empty();
        $('#a1_title').append("<option>loading....</option>");
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "drpdwn.php",
        contentype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        sucess:function(data){
        $('#a1_title').empty();
        $('#a1_title').append("<option value='0' >----select name-</option>");

        $.each(data,function(i,item){
        $('#a1_title').append('<option value="'+ data[i].id +'" >'+ data[i].name +'</option>');

        });
        },
        complete: function(){

        }

        });

        }
        $(document).ready(function(){

        dropdown();
        });

        </script>
        <select id="a1_title">
        </select>  
</body>
</html>
```

This is drpdwn`.php` file:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$pass = "admin"; 
$db = "Querybuilderdb"; 

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM tab";
$result = pg_query($con, $query);
if(pg_num_rows($result)){

$data=array();
while($row=pg_fetch_array($result))
{ $data[] = array(
'id'=>$row['id'],
'name' =>$row['name']
);

}

echo  json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

I have update my code here Can anyone please tell me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now by using getJSON

```
<html><body>
        <select id="a1_title">
        </select>
        <select id="a2_title">
        </select> 
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){


          $.getJSON("drpdwn.php", success = function(data){

        var items="";
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
               items +="<option value='"+ data[i].toLowerCase() +"'>" + data[i] +"</option>";
            }
            $("#a1_title").append(items); 
            $("#a1_title").change();
          });


        $("#a1_title").change(function(){
        $("#a2_title").html("");

          $.getJSON("second_dropdown.php?tabs="+ $(this).val(),success = function(data){
        alert("okay");
           var items="";
           for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
              items+="<option value='"+data[i].toLowerCase()+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>";

            }

            $("#a2_title").append(items); 
          });
        });

        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply echo out the results?

```
<?php

$query = "select distinct levelone as Name from tab limit 1";

$res = pg_query($con, $query)
?>
<select name="dbname" id="dbname" >
<?php
while $row = pg_fetch_assoc($res) {
   echo "<option>" . $row['levelone'] . "</option>";
}
?>
<select>
```

Comment: because i wanted to fetch data  on popup window that's why .. if is there any other way please tell me ..thanks in advance :)

Comment: Open another connection in the popup?

Comment: i just tried by opening another  connection in the popup. but its not working.

Comment: Is there any other way to fetch the data from postgres SQL into popup window please tell me...I'm totally stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do is rather than using two files why not echo the entire file from the PHP script thus the page loads when the result is returned from your query?

Comment: i think need to use ajax for calling this php file ...but i don't know how to use this . if you can help on this.

Comment: AJAX is always more risky. Why would you need "Live" updating options?

Comment: because its related from name of state village information. in this code here i'm simply trying to fetch data into combobox. If you can identify the error.. please help on that .

Comment: Rather than json_ecode()'ing everything try echoing out the completed HTML then closing the combo back on the HTML side

Comment: i didn't get you ...can you please edit on the code i have shown here... where i need to change on it..